# spring data rest update produce cross join sql error

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I want to use spring data rest to update rows of certain user , but at run time this query has strange "cross join" added to the query .

spring data rest method

```
 @Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("Update Notification n SET n.noticed = true Where n.notificationPost.owner.userId = 1 ")
public void postNoticed();
```

run time created query

```
Hibernate: update notification cross join  set noticed=true where owner_id=?
```

My only concern is why "cross join" added as it gives sql error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "cross"
```

I call this method directly by rest invoke , and also from mvc controller, both ways produce the same error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us some entities code snippet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found solution as stated in http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/114271-spring-data-jpa-modifying-query-failure

"No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins. "(Hibernate doc reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core.../#batch-direct)."

So I edited my code to use sub query

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("Update Notification n SET n.noticed = true Where n.notificationPost.postId in (SELECT n2.notificationPost.postId FROM Notification n2  where n2.notificationPost.owner.userId =:#{#security.principal.user.userId}) ")
public int postNoticed();
```

Comment: This applies only to DML-style operations.

Comment: both links are dead ;c

Comment: you saved me, had no clue from where the cross coming in the SQL. Thanks a ton.